# Volley Request call URL multiple times

Tags: android, android-volley

I have recently started on Android development platform. I am using Android Studio, and using Volley library for network operation. I have implemented a backend for push notification for iOS and it is working very well, and now I am triggering this php via Volley network operation as follows.

For some reasons it calls that URL multiple times (5 or 6 times), how do I know? because iOS device receives multiple notifications. I am not sure why this happens and how I could solve it?

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == buttonBuy) {
            message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.offerText);
            buy();
        }
}

private void buy()
 {
     StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.ASK_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams()
            {
                Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("token",token);
                params.put("pname",objee.optString("pname"));
                params.put("toid",objee.optString("uid"));
                params.put("pid",pid);
                params.put("message",message.getText().toString().trim());
                return params;
            }
        };

        CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(this).getRequestQueue().add(postRequest);
}
```

Comment: By the above code it won't call more than 1 time. May be you are calling `buy()` method or by your logic `buy()` method is called 5-6 times

Comment: For sure, I click the `buyButton` only once. I have added the rest of code where I call `buy()` method.

Comment: Add some log statements to the buy method and to the code calling it to find out what is going on.

Comment: Print log in `buy()` method as Henry suggested.

Comment: Try using `postRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 2, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));`

Comment: BNK, where should I put that code?

Comment: @Henry and Clairvoyant, I have put Log.d, and it only called once, no solution.

Comment: Right above the line `CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(this).getRequestQueue().add(postRequest);`

Comment: BNK, I have done it, but still same.

Comment: Ok, try put logging as @Henry suggests

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following code:

```
int socketTimeout = 10000; //10 seconds - change to what you want
RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
postRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
```